# quickly go to begin or end of the cell in org table

Tags: org-mode

Given that the cell has already some string values filled in and the cursor is located somewhere at the middle of the cell.
How to quickly move cursor the the first/last char of the very same cell? I know C-a, C-e but it has scope of the whole line instead of one cell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want `M-a` and `M-e` (respectively, `org-backward-sentence` and `org-forward-sentence`).